# Interface initialization(Name of city)?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface which has another interface as its property:

```
public interface IUserContactInformation
{
    bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }

    ICity City { get; set; 
}

public interface ICity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and class

```
public class City : ICity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IRegion Region { get; set; }

    public static City ConvertFromModel(CityLimited modelCity)
    {
        City city = new City();
        city.Id = modelCity.Id;
        city.Name = modelCity.Name;


        return city;
    }
```

How can I now initialize city name?

When I use

```
ICity city = new City();
```

I get:

> cannot implicity convert type..

I also tried

```
IUserContactInformation contact = new IUserContactInformation();
contact.City.Name = model.City;
```

but I get an error

Comment: Please post the full errors. There might be some namespacing issues.

Comment: {"Unable to cast object of type 'Model.City' to type 'Membership.ICity'."}

Comment: Currently with the code you've given (that we can compile), everything works as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ng6x5J. Please post code that shows the problem you're seeing.

Comment: userContactInformation.City = new City(); there i get an error

Comment: `IUserContactInformation contact = new IUserContactInformation();`? you can't create instance of interface